# Determine the basis and dimension of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Determine the basis and dimension of vector space generated by $\{u + v + w, v + w + z, w + z + u, z + u + v\}$ where $u, v, z, w$ are linearly independent vectors.

What's the best way to do it? I have tried to do it with vectors $(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)$ but I'm not sure whether I can solve it generally that way.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! In order to get a positive feedback, it's important to show what you have tried, and where you had any trouble.

Comment: Working with vectors like that amounts to just choosing a basis, so it is justified.

Answer (score 0):

Using Gauss-Jordan elimination convert 
$
A =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  u & v & w & 0 \\
0 & v & w & z \\
u & 0 & w & z \\
u & v & 0 & z
 \end{pmatrix}$

to this:
$
A =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  u & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & v & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & w & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & z
 \end{pmatrix}$

from there you can see that all four vectors are linearly independent. So the basis of A will be: $\left\{{(u, 0, 0, 0), (0, v, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, w, 0), (0, 0, 0, z)}\right\}$ And $\dim{A} = 4$

EDIT: By defenition, dimension of a vector space is a size of its basis, therefore here dimension is 4